# I have filled my jtable using following code but i m not able to set header of the column of the table

Tags: java, jtable, jtableheader

```
ResultSet rs = statment.executeQuery();
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: `set header of the column of the table`  ?? what does it mean ?

Comment: You should place the table into a JScrollPane. So you can get the header-line.

Comment: i have tried JScrollPane but its not working for header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot set column names which are selected from a database, but you can copy data out of that column in a new column and set the name of that new column.

Or else you can get that column name using this code.. :)

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
String name = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
```

Where `1` is the index of the column.